# Oracle sql Join tables based on one table containing the word in the field of another table

Tags: sql, oracle, regexp-substr

I'm trying to join two tables together as follows.

```
Table A        Table B
Field1         Field1
GO             GO
FOREGO
OK GO
```

I only want to join where the field1 in table A has the exact word as a word in table B, but is not part of another word.  So GO and OK GO would join successfully, FOREGO would not be allowed to join.

I have a hunch that i'd use reg_exp to accomplish the join, but I can't figure out how to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a hunch that i'd use reg_exp to accomplish the join, but I can't figure out how to implement.

You could use `REGEXP_LIKE`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.*
FROM TableA A
JOIN TAbleB B
 ON regexp_like(A.Field1, '( |^)('|| B.Field1|| ')( |$)');
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4a63d6e6e527a5b90fd48f9007b02f0c)**

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that words are surrounded by spaces, you could do:

```
select a.*
from a join
     b
     on ' ' || a.field1 || ' ' like '% ' || b.field1 || ' %';
```

Neither this method nor the version using `regexp_substr()` is going to have very good performance.  I would suggest that you parse the words out of table b into another table, and use a simple equijoin.